# Replace a column with something else of the same name, but keep populating it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I'm updating a system to have a more normalized database schema. Currently we have a `builds` table with a `user` column that stores a username as text. I'd like to add a `user_id` column and a `users` table, and have `some_build.user` return the user model. Pretty straightforward so far.

Unfortunately, the tests on this codebase are less thorough than you'd hope. In the event we have to roll back the change, I'd like to keep populating the old `user` column. I tried putting this in `build.rb`:

```
alias_attribute :legacy_username, :user
before_save do
  if changed_attributes.keys.include? 'user_id'
    legacy_username = user.name
  end
end
```

I was hoping it would write to the `user` column, while leaving `Build#user` pointed at the `User` model. Unfortunately, `legacy_username` ends up aliasing the `user` method, not the `user` column--that is, `some_build.legacy_username` returns a `User`, and the before_save hook is not successful.

Is there a way I can coördinate this while keeping everything called `user`, or do I need to rename something?

Answer (score 0):

Aha! Turns out you can set database values directly using `ActiveRecord::Base#[]=`:

```
before_save do
  if changed-attributes.keys.include? 'user_id'
    self[:user] = username
  end
end
```

No alias needed.